# signoutForm on stateless page

Tags: java, wicket

i have a web site which is created by wicket(java) but in special cases i got following error.

```
WicketMessage: unable to find component with path signoutForm on stateless page [Page class = ir.pnusn.ui.Dispatcher, id = 1, version = 0] it could be that the component is inside a repeater make your component return false in getStatelessHint()

Root cause:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: unable to find component with path signoutForm on stateless page [Page class = ir.pnusn.ui.Dispatcher, id = 1, version = 0] it could be that the component is inside a repeater make your component return false in getStatelessHint()
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkableListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkableListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.java:148)
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:91)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1175)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1252)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1353)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:493)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:355)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:200)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Can you provide more information? (page code, template, what are the "special cases", ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a wicket bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1897